# Optimizing a Laplace distribution's scale parameter for rejection sampling in R

Tags: r, sampling

I am using the Laplace distribution (location = 0, scale = b) to sample from a standard normal distribution. The normal distribution ranges from -1 to 2. I am using the rejection sampling method. In other words, the Laplace function is the envelope function.

I can't create any plots without specifying the scale b, so I decided to look for the best value that b can take.

I thought about finding the MLE of the envelope function, using some observations sampled from the normal distribution.

This is my R code:

```
# Define the log-likelihood function
log_likelihood <- function(b, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  -n*log(2*b) - sum(abs(x))/b
}

# Generate the data
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x <- x[x >= -1 & x <= 2]  # Restrict the range to [-1, 2]

# Find the maximum likelihood estimate of b
fit <- optim(par = 1, fn = log_likelihood, x = x, lower = 0)
b <- fit$par

# Plot the Laplace envelope function
curve((1/(2*b))*exp(-abs(x)/b), from = -5, to = 5, ylim = c(0, 0.4), ylab = "Density", xlab = "x")
```

The code above generates a sample of 1000 observations from a standard normal distribution and restricts the range to [-1, 2]. Then it uses the optim() function to find the value of b that maximizes the log-likelihood function. Finally, it plots the Laplace envelope function with the estimated value of b.

```
y <- seq(-1, 2, length = 1000)
z <- dnorm(y)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(y, z, type = "l", xlab = "X", ylab = "Density", main = "Standard Normal Distribution")
```

The plot below shows the two functions:

[image]

It turns out that b=1. I would appreciate some feedback regarding the process I followed here, I am not sure if it is correct. When I modify my code a bit, I get a different plot and a different b value.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for here. If you have questions about the underlying statistical theory, the Cross Validated site would probably be a better fit. Otherwise, please explain what is "wrong" or unexpected about the results, and what your desired result is instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do the optimization with the following code. I changed the sign of the objective function.

```
# Define the log-likelihood function
log_likelihood <- function(b, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  return(n*log(2*b) + sum(abs(x))/b)
}

# Generate the data
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x <- x[x >= -1 & x <= 2]  # Restrict the range to [-1, 2]

# Find the maximum likelihood estimate of b
fit <- optim(par = 1, fn = log_likelihood, x = x)
b <- fit$par

# Plot the Laplace envelope function
curve((1/(2*b))*exp(-abs(x)/b), from = -5, to = 5, ylim = c(0, 0.4), ylab = "Density", xlab = "x")
curve(dnorm(x), add = TRUE, col = "red")

b

0.5892578
```